# C/C++ Valid pointer but getting EXC_BAD_ACCESS and KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS

Tags: c++, c, macos, opengl

I've been racking my brain over this for hours and I can't find anything.

Potentially relevant information:

- Running on OSX 10.10.1 Yosemite
- This same code works perfectly fine on Windows.
- Every time I run this, it breaks at the exact same spot.
- The application is an OpenGL app that uses glfw3 to create a window.
- There are no threads, it's just a single threaded app, so the pointer is not being overwritten or being deallocated.
- These two methods are contained in two separate .c files that are compiled as c++ and contained within a built library that I link to. Other methods in the library work just fine.

  ```
  OPchar* OPstreamReadLine(OPstream* stream) {
      OPchar buffer[500];
      i32 len, i;

      // ALL WORKS FINE
        // check to see if we are at the end of the stream or not
        if(stream->_pointer >= stream->Length) return 0;

        // Prints out the contents of the stream, and the start of the pointer just fine
        OPlog("Buffer %s | Pointer %d", stream->Data, stream->_pointer);
        sscanf((OPchar*)stream->Data  stream->_pointer, "%500[^\n]", buffer);
        len = strlen(buffer);
        stream->_pointer = len  1;

        // Spits out 'Read Hello of len 5'
        OPlog("Read %s of len %d", buffer, len);



      // ISSUE STARTS HERE
      // OPchar is a typedef of char
      // STEP 1. Make the call
      OPchar* result = OPstringCreateCopy(buffer);

      // STEP 6. The Pointer is printed out correctly, its the same thing
      // ex: Pos: 0xd374b4
      OPlog("Pos: 0x%x", result);

      // STEP 7. This is where it breaks
      // EXC_BAD_ACCESS and KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS
      // What happened? 
      // Did returning the pointer from the function break it?
      OPlog("len: %d", strlen(result));

      OPlog("Result %s", result);

      return result;
  }


  OPchar* OPstringCreateCopy(const OPchar* str) {
      i32 len = strlen(str);

      // STEP 2. Prints out 'Hello 5'
      OPlog("%s %d", str, len);

      // Allocates it (just uses malloc)
      OPchar* result = (OPchar*)OPalloc(sizeof(OPchar) * (len + 1));

      // Copies the previous string into the newly created one
      strcpy(result, str);

      // Ensures that it's null terminated
      // even though strcpy is supposed to do it
      result[len] = NULL;

      // STEP 3. Gives a good pointer value
      // ex: Pos: 0xd374b4
      OPlog("Pos: 0x%x", result);

      // STEP 4. Prints out '5'
      OPlog("len: %d", strlen(result));

      // STEP 5. Prints out 'Hello'
      OPlog("hmmm: %s", result);

      // Just return this same pointer
      return result;
   }
  ```

I've since replaced these functions with versions that don't use the sscanf stuff which got around the issue, however I'm now hitting the same problem with another returned pointer becoming invalid. This example was simpler to explain, so I thought I'd start there.

Comment: If you have to use C-style formatting functions, use correct conversion specifiers. %d is not the right one for size_t, and %x is not the right one for pointers.

Comment: Finally, if you don't get any warnings about this code even with -Wall, consider filing a bug report against whatever software provides OPlog, it's their responsibility to make sure you are getting the warnings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a theory, which you may go test. Instead of using `%x` to print your pointers, use `%p` instead. You may be on a 64-bit OS and not realizing it. The problem could be that you did not supply a prototype for `OPstringCreateCopy`, in which case the return value was treated as an `int` (32 bits) instead of a pointer (64 bits). Since you are only printing out 32 bits of `result`, it seems like the pointer is valid, but the upper 32 bits may have been lost.

The fix for this is to make sure you always supply prototypes for all your functions.  There should be some compiler warnings that you can turn on to assist you with finding uses of unprototyped functions.  You might also want to go through your code and check for any other 64-bit problems, such as if you ever cast a pointer to an int.